# What are some good matetials for learning about group extensions?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, simple-groups, group-extensions

I'm working through Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra for self-study, and I'm interested in reading some more in depth discussions of the group extension problem. Specifically, I am interested in how to reconstruct finite groups from their composition series. Are there any good introductory books or papers on the topic?

Comment: What about the bibliography entries of [this article](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Extension_of_a_group)?